# Drupal Zen subtheme creation problem: sidebars, header and footer regions disappear

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

I am currently trying to create a Drupal theme as a Zen subtheme, by doing the following:

- I created a new Zen subtheme by following instructions in ["How to build your own sub-theme (6.x-2.x)"](http://drupal.org/node/629510) documentation
- The problem is that when I enable the new theme, no header, footer or sidebars are displayed. When the new theme is enabled, these regions disappear also from main Zen theme.
- I am using Drupal 6.16 with Zen 6.x-2.0
- I have succesfully created Zen subthemes with previous version of Zen (6.x-1.x), so I suspect this problem has something to do with the new version of Zen

Since Drupal doesn't display any error messages related to this issue, I am totally puzzled. Therefore any tips on how to debug or solve this problem are MUCH appreciated!

The following debugging has already been done:

- Apache error / access logs give no new insight
- Region variables (`$content_top`, `$content_bottom`, `$header`, etc.) in `page.tpl.php` are empty

Comment: Try inspect the page.tpl.php and see what variables you have available. It should give you some clues as to what is going on.

Comment: Good point. I did try that out and the variables are empty. I documented that to my question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I was able to work around the problem by using Zenophile:

- Installed and configured Zenophile
- Created new Zen subtheme with it
- Copied all customized files from my old sub-theme to the newly created Zenophile base

If nobody can tell me a better approach in a couple of days, I will close this question from my behalf and proceed with this approach in the future as well.